# Charging Lithium ion battery with a modified charger

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger

I've a defective charger for a small LED torch light, its output is 4.2V / 500mA.

I may not find an alternative one, so I'm considering modifying a mobile phone charger as following:

- The mobile phone charger has output of 5V / 1 or 2 Amps.
- I put at the output three diodes: 1N4007, and two schottky diodes of about 0.1V voltage drop each: 0.65 + 0.2 = 0.85 V
- So the output becomes: 5-.85 = 4.15V (edited )

Is this voltage adequate and suitable to charge the battery? Is it safe to use?
Let me know your thoughts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add a schematic if possible. Charging Li+ improperly can yield spectacularly pyrotechnic events.

Comment: Likely unsafe. The forward volt drop of a diode depends on current and this means the output will rise about 4.2 volts when delivering low currents. Go buy one.

Comment: Phone chargers are not chargers, they are constant-voltage power supplies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original charger had only 4.2V which leaves no room for a charger driver

This means the charger had the charging logic inside.

A diode is still conducting a small current even under it's forward voltage.

You better use a dedicated module like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DRT4PWY) that can be modified for 500mA, using a diode will overcharge or even destroy your battery